# How to display a multiple values in textfield?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to the iPhone. I have four number buttons like 1,2,3,4. When I click any button the value is displayed in a textfield, but when I click two buttons only one value is displayed in textfield.

How to display in multiple values in textfield?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a values in textfield?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034762/how-to-display-a-values-in-textfield)

Answer (score 1):

You can add new string value to already displayed value in your text field, for example, in following way:

```
UITextField *field; // <- reference to your UITextField
NSString *value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] stringValue]; // <- value to add
field.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", field.text, value];
```